# Trouble finding the input in this circuit diagram

Tags: diagram

[image]

Currently having trouble finding the input in my circuit diagram. I am assuming "z" is my output. As of now my input equations I have figured to be:

Da = BC

Db = CB' + BC' = C(+)B

Dc = C'A'

Z = A

I need to write up the state diagram and the sequential circuit for this diagram, but I'm stuck on the lack of an apparent input.

Comment: Well, there's a reset input. Not all sequential circuits have an input, however.

Comment: There's a clock input? Perhaps it is reset first, making it 0, and then from each clock onwards, Z changes in some fashion?

Comment: You don't need an input. As stated, you have Reset, which is bringing your state to a known value. Think about it as some sort of counter (some counters are not having inputs as well).

Comment: @EugeneSh. So then would I notate the reset's value onto the state diagram?

Comment: The Reset is transitioning from any state into the initial state.

Answer (score 1):

The inputs to that circuit are Clock and Reset.

Reset will clear all the flip-flops, and successive clock pulses will cause the flip-flops to "count" in some strange way.